# Python cannot find the file path to write the output

Tags: python

I have the following static method in Python.

```
import subprocess   

class ProcessUtility:

    @staticmethod
    def execute_command(url):
        process = None
        process = subprocess.check_output(["phantomas " + url  + " --har=test.har"])
        return process
```

It command basically writes the output to test.har file. I have created the test.har file in the same directory as that of the script and given it read,write and execute permissions.

Upon executing I get the error.

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Any ideas why I keep getting this.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to `subprocerss.check_output()`. It's been so long since I've had to check the docs for `subprocess` that I'd never noticed the new addition for 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most `subprocess` functions take a list of arguments as opposed to a string, if `shell=False` (the default). Try

```
process = subprocess.check_output(['phantomas', url, '--har=test.har'])
```

Comment: Note `shell=True` can lead to unexpected behaviour. Be sure to check the docs for what it implies (essentially, arguments are interpreted as going to the *shell*, rather than the program).